# New table with a foreign key to identityuser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want my newly created table userId to be a foreign key to IdentityUser.
The scenario is that, I want each user to have a favorite movie, so how do I go about this?

```
public class FavoriteMovie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Amount { get;set; }
    public string WhereIsBeenSold { get;set; }
}
```

I want if a user add a friend and click on his profile, he should be able to view that particular friend's favorite movie info.

How do I set the relation between then and also how do I make the friend name click-able so that he can be navigated to his favorite movie?

Comment: do you want a help to create the database or??

Comment: u need help in creating the relation ship, u need sql or u want to know how this can be maintained..?

Comment: I need help with the relationship

Comment: Not clear what you really want do you want to use this table as relation to another table?

Comment: go to this link it will help you to understand your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216915/how-to-get-user-profile-data-from-asp-net-mvc-custom-identityuser-model?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can design your database as like this:

1.Create User table which has unique/primary key identification for each user.

2. Then create Movie table which consists of movie information.

3.Make your user id as a foreign key to the Movie table.

If you want more help inform me

Comment: On creating the user table, i think the identitymodel.cs is a good start so how do i write in their relationships?